# iOS app notifications when app is open (like whatsapp)

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, swift2

Im actually receiving the notifications with a JSON and a message, so what i wanted was handle that notification and show it to the user.

When the app is not running or in background, the message is shown, but when the app is open there is no notification. In fact, i receive the json when in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`, but what i want is a notification box like whatsapp do.

Like this:

[image]

I have this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    print("Notification received: \(userInfo)")
    let notification = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary
    let message = notification?.valueForKey("alert")
}
```

And this in ´didfinishlaunchWithOptions´

```
let readAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
        readAction.identifier = "READ_IDENTIFIER"
        readAction.title = "Read"
        readAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Foreground
        readAction.destructive = false
        readAction.authenticationRequired = true

        let deleteAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
        deleteAction.identifier = "DELETE_IDENTIFIER"
        deleteAction.title = "Delete"
        deleteAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Foreground
        deleteAction.destructive = true
        deleteAction.authenticationRequired = true

        let ignoreAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
        ignoreAction.identifier = "IGNORE_IDENTIFIER"
        ignoreAction.title = "Ignore"
        ignoreAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Foreground
        ignoreAction.destructive = false
        ignoreAction.authenticationRequired = false

        let messageCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
        messageCategory.identifier = "MESSAGE_CATEGORY"
        messageCategory.setActions([readAction, deleteAction], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal)
        messageCategory.setActions([readAction, deleteAction, ignoreAction], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)

        let types: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound, UIUserNotificationType.Alert]

        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(
            UIUserNotificationSettings(
                forTypes: types,
                categories: (NSSet(array: [messageCategory])) as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>))

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()

        let notTypes:UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
        let noteSettings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notTypes, categories: nil)

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(noteSettings)
```

Hope anyone could help. Thanks for all

Comment: Try re-phrasing your question to, "I have a string and I want to put it in a label".

Answer (score 7):

When your application is on foreground, iOS will not show the notification banner. You have to show yourself. You can use some of those 3rd codes to show the banner and handle the touche on the banner to process the appropriated codes:

https://github.com/KrauseFx/TSMessages
https://github.com/terryworona/TWMessageBarManager

In your call-back didReceiveRemoteNotification, check the application state:

```
if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive ) {
// show your banner
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have to create a view, customize it with your content and show it on the application window.

There are also frameworks that do that for you, like [CWStatusBarNotification](https://github.com/cezarywojcik/CWStatusBarNotification)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use additional frameworks or libraries. In iOS 10, you can use the method `userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)`.

This method is only called if you add to payload the attribute `content-available:1`. The payload should be something like:

```
{
     "aps":{
          "alert":"Testing.. (7)",
          "badge":1,"sound":"default"
     },
     "content-available":1
}
```